# remote action inside repeat panel causing an error

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, remote-action

I am using remote action for displaying records on the visual force page.My remote action method is inside repeat tag when i rerender my repeat my remote action is not functioning.

I am getting the following error:

> No remoted actions found to resolve
>   No remoted actions found to resolve '$RemoteAction.S_R.Images'Error is in expression '{!$RemoteAction.S_R.Images}' in component  in page pw_r

Can i know how to rerender the panel with repeat tag and i cannot write remote action outside repeat panel. Can i know how to rerender remote action inside repeat pannel.

The error is not getting displayed when thye page is refreshed completely and this is loosing my url parameters and i dont want to refresh my complete page.

Comment: Suggest you post the remote action part of your controller and perhaps all of your page to give people more context to base an answer on.

Comment: I am just wondering why do you need remote action inside repeat ? Cannot you declare the same outside and send some parameters from the repeat ?

Comment: i need it inside repeat tag because i am sending the value from repeat to remote action